# Why click event calls two time in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have made small plugin for practice. But on click on first span it is printing in console two times. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/583vN/)

```
$.fn.sample= function(options){
  var setting= $.extend({
    d:false
  }, options)
  $(this).append($('<span/>').attr({id:'jitender'}).text('hi click me'))
  $('span').click(function(){
    if(setting.d)
      console.log(1)
    else
      console.log(2)
  })
  return this
}
$(function(){
  $('div.one').sample({
    d:true
  })

  $('div.two').sample({
    d:false
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the click event to all span tags every time you call sample. I expect you actually want something like this:

```
var clickSpan = $('<span/>').attr({id:'jitender'}).text('hi click me');
$(this).append(clickSpan);
clickSpan.click(function(){
    if(setting.d)
      console.log(1);
    else
      console.log(2);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/583vN/3/

Answer (score 1):

`$('span').click` will attach itself to all span tags.

Change:

```
$('span').click(function()
```

To:

```
$(this).click(function()
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/583vN/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting an event handler on all `<span>`s each time you call the plugin.  You can fix this by being more specific with your handler in the plugin, changing:

```
  $('span').click(function(){
    if(setting.d)
      console.log(1)
    else
      console.log(2)
  })
```

When this is executed on a `click` on a `<span>`, you've set two handlers, each of which get called.

Change the above to the following (*which limits the click even to spans in the element the plugin is being called on*):

```
  $('span', this).click(function(){
    if(setting.d)
      console.log(1);
    else
      console.log(2);
  });
```

See this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/hikay/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have attached two event handlers to that span...

It happens because when you are calling `$('span').click(...)` - you are attaching vent handler to all spans in a document...

If you want to attach it only to span in div to which you are applying sample plugin- write: `$('span', this).click(...)`